# Pantalla en blanco al realizar una tarea

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

He creado mi primer tema de Wordpress y funciona todo perfectamente salvo por un detalle que no sé muy bien que será.

Al activar un plugin cualquiera, publicar una entrada, o guardar los ajustes, me sale un **pantallazo en blanco justo después de pulsar el botón** (el de Publicar, Guardar cambios, activar un plugin)

Lo curioso es que **estas tareas que hago las realiza correctamente** pese al pantallazo blanco al final.

Alguna idea de que puede ser o por donde puedo empezar a buscar el problema?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Arregado.

Un **espacio antes del cierre ?>** de la etiqueta de PHP en el archivo functions.php me generaba el inconveniente.